# ¿Cómo adquirió "morocho" los significados de "mellizo" y "falto de dientes"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, diferencias-regionales

El Diccionario de la Lengua define [**morocho**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PqbyAYy) como

> Del quechua *muruch'u* 'variedad de maíz muy duro'.
>
> 1. adj. Arg., Bol., Par., Perú y Ur. Dicho de una persona: **Que tiene la piel morena.**
>   2. adj. Arg., Par. y Ur. Dicho de una persona: **Que tiene pelo negro.**
>   3. adj. Nic. Dicho de una persona, y especialmente de un niño: **Falto de algunos dientes.**
>   4. adj. Ven. **mellizo** (‖ nacido de un mismo parto). U. t. c. s.
>   5. adj. coloq. Ec. y Hond. Dicho de una persona: **Robusta y bien conservada.**
>   6. m. Chile, Col., Ec., Perú y Ur. **maíz morocho.**

Si el maíz morocho es de color obscuro y duro, es fácil entender que la palabra "morocho" tenga las acepciones (1), (2) y (6) y, figuradamente, la (5), pero ¿las acepciones 3 y 4?

¿Cómo adquirió "morocho" los significados de "falto de algunos dientes" y "mellizo"en Nicaragua y Venezuela, respectivamente?

Comment: Pues el diccionario de americanismos [recoge](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=wWzj56Seyx0AeMvOP6M|debUYRFLnx0AejpvFgz|gyYHOBHslx0ANev4Fe7) aún más acepciones interesantes.

Answer (score 3):

Pues resulta que la acepción "mellizo" es mucho más cercana al origen etimológico de *morocho* que la acepción más conocida *de piel oscura* (que proviene de una asimilación fonética con *moreno*). En [esta publicación](https://books.google.cl/books?id=rJK9DAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA15&dq=morocho%20gemelo&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q=morocho%20gemelo&f=false) acerca de los gemelos se dan las pistas.

El quechua es la principal lengua andina. En quechua la palabra **muruch'u** significa "duro". De ahí que el DRAE indique que *morocho* viene de una "variedad de maíz muy duro" (*muruch'u sara*). *Muruchhu* es una cosa dura de comer.

Al hablarse de personas, *muruch'u runa* significa "hombre fuerte" (en la acepción 5 del DRAE). Y este significado "fuerte, robusto" también lo usan en los países andinos en frases como *hambre morocha* y *sueño morocho*.

Pues bien, a veces tenemos la suerte de encontrar huevos grandes con 2 yemas. A esos se les dice *huevos morochos*. Lo mismo los *plátanos morochos*. No porque sean oscuros o duros, sino por grandes y saludables. Y la palabra pasó a designar frutas, objetos y personas *dobles*.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando suceden estas cosas puede ser por varios motivos, uno de los cuales es que el término se haya fusionado con otro cercano. Puedo dar una hipótesis sobre la acepción de Nicaragua de "falto de algunos dientes", y es que hay una palabra muy cercana en pronunciación que es **[moroncho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pql7PkM)**, que significa lo mismo que *morondo*:

> **[morondo, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pqp4Qsh)**
>
> Forma fest. de *mondo*.
>
> 1. adj. Pelado o mondado de cabellos o de hojas.

No es descabellado pensar que en algunos sitios se haya asemejado el hecho de que a un niño se le caigan los dientes de leche al hecho de que a un árbol se le caigan las hojas para luego volverle a salir, y posteriormente los términos "moroncho" y "morocho" se confundieran y fusionaran.

Desgraciadamente no he podido encontrar nada para comprobar mi teoría, ni tampoco nada para explicar la acepción de Venezuela, pero dejo la respuesta aquí por si sirve de algo o por si inspiro a alguien a buscar otra explicación.